# Log4Net Levels Numeric Values

Tags: log4net

I can't seem to find the numeric values for the predefined levels in Log4Net. Can anybody point me to them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an excerpt from the Level class (decompiled with .net reflector)

```
  public static readonly Level Alert = new Level(0x186a0, "ALERT");
    public static readonly Level All = new Level(-2147483648, "ALL");
    public static readonly Level Critical = new Level(0x15f90, "CRITICAL");
    public static readonly Level Debug = new Level(0x7530, "DEBUG");
    public static readonly Level Emergency = new Level(0x1d4c0, "EMERGENCY");
    public static readonly Level Error = new Level(0x11170, "ERROR");
    public static readonly Level Fatal = new Level(0x1adb0, "FATAL");
    public static readonly Level Fine = new Level(0x7530, "FINE");
    public static readonly Level Finer = new Level(0x4e20, "FINER");
    public static readonly Level Finest = new Level(0x2710, "FINEST");
    public static readonly Level Info = new Level(0x9c40, "INFO");
    private readonly string m_levelDisplayName;
    private readonly string m_levelName;
    private readonly int m_levelValue;
    public static readonly Level Notice = new Level(0xc350, "NOTICE");
    public static readonly Level Off = new Level(0x7fffffff, "OFF");
    public static readonly Level Severe = new Level(0x13880, "SEVERE");
    public static readonly Level Trace = new Level(0x4e20, "TRACE");
    public static readonly Level Verbose = new Level(0x2710, "VERBOSE");
    public static readonly Level Warn = new Level(0xea60, "WARN");
```

Answer (score 33):

The trunk code for [`Level.cs`](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4net/trunk/src/Core/Level.cs?view=markup) gives these numbers:

- Off: int.MaxValue (2,147,483,647; 0x7FFFFFFF)
- Emergency: 120000
- Fatal: 110000
- Alert: 100000
- Critical: 90000
- Severe: 80000
- Error: 70000
- Warn: 60000
- Notice: 50000
- Info: 40000
- Debug: 30000
- Fine: 30000
- Trace: 20000
- Finer: 20000
- Verbose: 10000
- Finest: 10000
- All: int.MinValue (-2,147,483,648; 0x80000000)

Comment: Level.cs is now at http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4net/trunk/src/Core/Level.cs?view=markup.