# Log4Net: how to configure Threshold in run time?

Tags: log4net

I need to configure Threshold dynamically in run-time, I might have integer or string representation of the level in .net variable. Instead of getting one of this representations, log4net expects both them to be specified in constructor, which seems very weird to me:

```
public Level(int level, string levelName);
```

log4net team did not even trouble to explain why, all I found is this:

http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Core.LevelConstructor1.html

they do not even explain what this `int level` means, where can I find mapping for it? They just say that "higher values represent more severe levels" which is not enough.

I expected to have something like that:

```
appender.Threshold = new Level(level);
```

here `level` might be of string or int type

Answer (score 1):

The `Level` class has public static members for predefined levels such as Off, Error, Warning:

You probably want to set the `Threshold` property to one of these predefined levels, e.g.:

```
myAppender.Threshold = Level.Warn;
```

Alternatively, [as described in the documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Core.Level.html), you can set the level to one of the entries in a repository's LevelMap.

**UPDATE**

> Do you mean I have to work it out from their order? like Off maps to 0 (or 1?),

Not at all: Off maps to `Level.Off.Value`; and similarly for the others.

Comment: I need to set level in run time, so the value is only known in run-time, and can be stored in some sort of variable. Like variable `level` in the example `appender.Threshold = new Level(level)`. `LevelMap` has same sort of constructor, it does not explain which int value maps to which specific level

Comment: @YMC, If you look at the predefined levels (Level.Warn, Level.Error etc) you'll see which values correspond to which levels.

Comment: Do you mean I have to work it out from their order? like Off maps to 0 (or 1?), Emergency to 1 (or 2?), etc.?

Comment: The numeric values for the levels are listed in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998972/log4net-levels-numeric-values)

Comment: Also, remember when you change an appender at runtime you have to call `appender.ActivateOptions()` for the changes to take effect.

Comment: So my best bet is to implement mapper on my own like this: `switch (myLevelVariable) { case "TraceLevelOff": myAppender.Threshold = Level.Off; ... }`. Right? Looks like this Threshold integer values are not fixed and may change in time